# Regular Expression to match word ending with either y or z, but noth both together

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression which matches words ending with y or z, but not both together.

Here are some test cases:

```
fez day fyyyz fyyzy
```

- Matches `fez`
- Matches `day`
- Doesnt match `fyyyz` as it ends in `yz`
- Doesnt match `fyyzy` as it ends in `zy`

I was trying this regular expression, but it isn't working.

> `[yz\b]`

Regex Tool I am using is - http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Your specification is very vague. Which of these should match: `z`, `zz`, `yz`, `zy`, `yaz`, `fizz`, `flyy`, `gazza`, `buzzy`, `mayfly`, `untyz`, `bay z`, `bay y`, `boz x`, `box z`?

Comment: @Borodin if I understood correctly, anything that ends in 'z' but not in 'yz' OR ends in 'y' but not in 'zy' is OK.

Comment: The latest edit made the question crystal clear. The only trouble is the tags - @SamridhiDubey, please consider leaving just 1 or 2 *relevant* ones.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Are you writing to me? I didn't edit the question. If you're writing to whoever edited the tags then you can look at the edit history to see who made the change and put an `@callout` in your comment.

Comment: @Błotosmętek: Yes, I could make an intelligent guess too, but the OP needs to define his requirement properly or all we will have is guesses. In any case, we *still* don't know whether the single-character strings `z` and `y` or strings ending with `zz` or `yy` should match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
\b\w*[yz]\b(?<!yz)
```

or - if the word can't end with `yz` OR `zy`:

```
\b\w*[yz]\b(?<!yz|zy)
```

It matches any word ending with `y` or `z`, but not `yyz` (or with `(?<!yz|zy)`, not those ending with `yz` or `zy`).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5nLyL/1)

Note that `\b` inside square brackets is not a word boundary, but a backspace matching escape sequence.

*Pattern details*

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`, it can be adjusted to match just letters with `[^\W\d_]*`)
- `[yz]` - a `y` or `z`
- `\b` - trailing word boundary
- `(?<!yz)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `yz` char sequence immediately before the current location.

**EDIT**: Now, that all Perl, Python and Java tags are removed, it might also attract the attention of people who would like to use the regex in **VBA, C++ `std::regex`** (default flavor of which is ECMAScript5), or **JavaScript** whose regex engines (**ECMA-5 standard**) does not support lookbehinds, but do support lookaheads.

You may use

```
/\b(?!\w*(?:yz|zy)\b)\w*[yz]\b/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ZFwb1/1).

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?!\w*(?:yz|zy)\b)` - a negative lookahead that is executed right after finding a word boundary, and it will fail the match if after 0+ word chars, there is either `yz` or `zy` followed with the trailing word boundary
- `\w*` - consuming the 0+ word chars
- `[yz]` - `y` or `z`
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

Comment: @anubhava: Where did you get this requirement from?

Comment: `but not both together.`

Comment: @vks: Not a problem - `\b\w*[yz]\b(?<!yz|zy)`. However, it is not really clear to me what that *but not both together* means.

Comment: Yeah you both will correct your answers and it would be similar to what i posted first :P

Comment: @vks: That is a guessing game now. I followed the *fez day fyyyz -> Matches both fez and day, but not fyyyz as it ends with yz* bit.

Comment: yeah but the fact remains the same :P

Comment: Where did you get the idea of a word boundary from? It is a little unlikely that the OP's idea of a "word" is the same as a PCRE "word" character. `Fizz's lazy wildboyz play-group plaza`?

Answer (score 2):

```
\b\w*[yz](?<!(?:yz|zy))\b
```

Try this.Lookbehind will make sure you dont have `yz or zy` as end.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/Gtplnq/1

Comment: Why did you put the `yz` and `zy` into a non-capturing group? `(?<!(?:yz|zy))` = `(?<!yz|zy)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ahh answered after many days..... rusted a bit....strange thing....did not get a single upvote despite being correct at the first attempt........:P so has changed i guess

Comment: But you are still following your style - no space between the full stop and the next sentence capital letter. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah ...see ya later :)

Answer (score 1):

If your word are not 1 in length then use:

```
/\b\w*(?:[^z]y|[^y]z)\b/
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/13vhqQ/3)

If you can have 1 character word as well then you can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
/\b(?!\w*(?:yz|zy)\b)\w*[yz]\b/
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/13vhqQ/1)

Answer (score 1):

Another way, without lookbehinds:

```
/\w*(?:[^y]z|[^z]y)\b/
```

[Example](http://www.regexr.com/3g5sc)

Comment: This wont match `y` or `z`

Comment: It won't match the *words*, only their endings.